# show image on timer code. want to add close feature

Tags: javascript, html, image

I can't for the life of me figure out how to add an exit feature to my code. I want it so the user can click anywhere on the screen to make the image go away. Can someone help please?

HTML

```
<body>
<div align="center">
<img id="image" src="image1.png" height="200" width="200">
```

JS

```
var hidden = false;

setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("image").style.visibility= hidden ? "visible" : "";
hidden = !hidden;
},2000);
```

Comment: Could you explain clearly what are you going to achieve and what is your current problem?

Comment: I want it so, when the image appears, it stays. Until the user, (the person on my site) clicks off of it (anywhere on the screen.) @maheshiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is `visible`. You need to set to `hidden` when you want to hide it.

And you need to bind your code on the `click` event.

```js
var hidden = false;
window.document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("image").style.visibility = hidden ? "" : "hidden";
    hidden = !hidden; // comment out this line if you do not want to show again on click
}, false);
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200" height="200" width="200">
```

---

**Update 2**, if you want the timeout code to show the image after 2 seconds (*as mentioned in comments*) and then when you click anywhere to hide it *for ever* use

```js
var image = document.getElementById("image");

setTimeout(function() {
  image.style.visibility = 'visible';
  window.document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    image.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }, false);
}, 2000);
```

```css
#image {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200" height="200" width="200">
```

Comment: @CharieBurns added updated that uses the time out, and on click just changes the `hidden` value.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure if we are on the same page. I want it so in X time, the image will appear. Then, when the user clicks off of it, to stay hidden. (Until page refresh.)

Comment: @CharieBurns your timer is an interval which tries to alter the `visibility` property. Do you want to only show the image once after 2 seconds and then stay visible until you click, then it hides until refresh ?

Comment: I want it so when you load the page, the image is hidden. Lets say 10 seconds after being on the page, the image appears; and stays. I don't want the image after the 10 seconds to time out. I want it only to return to being hidden when the user clicks off of it. I don't want to it appear again until the page is refreshed and the process is started again.

Comment: @CharieBurns ok, added update with that functionality

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center">
<img id="image" src="image1.png" height="200" width="200">
</div>

<script>    
var hidden = false;

setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("image").style.visibility = "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";
},2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to make it simple..

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ritesh14887/pen/LbeqGX)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').click(function(){
    $('#image').hide();
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this.

```
        $(window).click(function() {
    //Hide the menus if visible
 document.getElementById("image").hide();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hidden = false;

setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("image").style.visibility= hidden ? "visible" : "";
hidden = !hidden;
},2000);

function myremove(){
  document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<body onclick="myremove()">
<div align="center">
<img id="image" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" height="200" width="200" style="display:block;">
  </div>
</body>
```